# Spring batch Dynamic change chunk size according to lines read

Tags: spring-batch

I need to dynamically change the chunk size depending on the number of lines read, the reason I need todo this is because each file represents a transaction, if one line didn't get inserted in the database correctly, I need to rollback the database for all the lines in the file?  How do I dynamically change the chunk size?  I found this but it was not very helpful  [Spring batch : dynamic chunk size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610830/spring-batch-dynamic-chunk-size?rq=1)

Comment: It should be possible if the input of your job is a single file. Is that an option for you? If yes, then you can create a first tasklet step that calculates the number of lines in the file and pass the info to dynamically configure a second chunk-oriented step to read/write the file. What if the file contains a large data set? You will have a single transaction for the whole file.. Have you thought about this scenario? A common technique is to use a staging table to validate the content then copy the data from the staging table to a production table.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have thought about a large data set and that is why I need to set the chunk size dynamically because my data set has x number of records each record length is not fixed. If each record has a fixed length setting a fixed chunk size would be simple, since each record is not fixed, I am amusing the best solution would be to extend the SimpleCompletionPolicy and define what should be considered complete keep track of the processed records to set the chunk size

Comment: I don't think a custom `CompletionPolicy` will solve your issue. What I mean is that if your input file has 1M records in it, are you ok to have a single transaction for 1M records? If you are ok with that, then you can have a first step calculate the number of lines in the file and pass the chunk size to a second step in the execution context. Otherwise, you can use a staging table in which you verify that everything is ok and if yes, copy it in a production table.